# Print details from a list in react-native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

i have a problem for stamp details from a list.                                                                                              I'm new to coding hope you can help me.

The questions are:

1. Do I have to do a new fetch for the detail or not?
2. Why in the console log speed and alignment are undefined? I I can't make them undefined

**racesDetails.tsx**

```
type RaceDetailsRouteProp = RouteProp<SubStackParamRaces, 'RaceDetails'>;


type RaceDetailsProps = {
    route: RaceDetailsRouteProp;
};



function RaceDetails({ route }: RaceDetailsProps) {
    const { iRaceDetails } = route.params;
    console.log(iRaceDetails)
    console.log(iRaceDetails.alignment)
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Index: {iRaceDetails.index}</Text>
        <Text>Name: {iRaceDetails.name}</Text>
        <Text>Speed: {iRaceDetails.speed}</Text>
        <Text>Alignment: {iRaceDetails.alignment}</Text>
        {/* Render other details based on IRaceDetails interface */}
      </View>
    );
  }
  
  export default RaceDetails;
```

**racesList.tsx**

```
const URL_API_RAZZE = 'https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/races';

type RaceList = {
  navigation: NativeStackNavigationProp<StackParamList, "RaceList">;
};



const RaceList = ({ navigation }: RaceList) => {
  const [raceList, setRaceList] = useState<IRaceList>({
    count: 0,
    results: []
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(URL_API_RAZZE)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((results: IRaceList) => {
        setRaceList(results);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
  }, []);


  const renderItem = ({ item }: { item: IRace }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.section}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("RaceDetails", { iRaceDetails: item })}
      >
        <RaceListCard iRace={item}></RaceListCard>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  return <FlatList data={raceList.results} renderItem={renderItem} />
};

export default RaceList;
```

**App.tsx**

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator<TabParamList>();
export type TabParamList = {
  Home: undefined,
  Party: undefined,
  Sfide: undefined
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
export type StackParamList = {
  Home: undefined,
  RaceList: undefined
  RaceDetails: { 
    iRaceDetails: IRaceDetails 
  }
}

const SubStackRaces = createNativeStackNavigator();
export type SubStackParamRaces = {
  RaceList: undefined,
  RaceDetails: { 
    iRaceDetails: IRaceDetails 
  };
};


  
function TabNavigator() {
  return (
      <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={Homepage}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: () => (
              <Image
                source={{
                  uri: 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/25/25694.png',
                  width: 30,
                  height: 30
                }}
                />
            )
          }}
        />

        <Tab.Screen
          name="Party"
          component={Party}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: () => (
              <Image
                source={{
                  uri: 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/4261/4261244.png',
                  width: 30,
                  height: 30
                }}
                />
            )
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
        name="Sfide"
        component={Sfide}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: () => (
            <Image
              source={{
                uri: 'https://static-00.iconduck.com/assets.00/challenge-icon-512x512-4525jsiu.png',
                width: 30,
                height: 30
              }}
              />
          )
        }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

const SubStackRacesNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <SubStackRaces.Navigator>
      <SubStackRaces.Screen name="RaceList" component={RaceList} />
      <SubStackRaces.Screen
        name="RaceDetails"
        component={RaceDetails}
      />
    </SubStackRaces.Navigator>
  );
};

function App() {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Homepage" component={TabNavigator} />
        <Stack.Screen name="RaceList" component={SubStackRacesNavigation} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**details-race.ts**

```
export interface IRaceDetails  {
    index: string
    name: string
    speed: number
    ability_bonuses: AbilityBonuse[]
    age: string
    alignment: string
    size: string
    size_description: string
    starting_proficiencies: StartingProficiency[]
    languages: Language[]
    language_desc: string
    traits: Trait[]
    subraces: Subrace[]
    url: string
  }
```

Thank a lot for the answer !!

Answer my questions.

Comment: The application is functional, except for the new detail page

Comment: You should consider adding more detail to your question and remove all the code that doesn't help answering your question. Also, there are no "bonus questions", whether you wrote a correct piece of code or not should not be a question to ask on stack overflow, we are not mentors. If you want to ask about a specific best practice then you should specify it on the question.

Comment: Please also clarify the question which isn't totally clear what you want to achieve

Comment: To display the details of a selected race, you don't necessarily need to do a new fetch. Instead, you can pass the selected race details directly from the RaceList component to the RaceDetails component using the navigation route params.

Comment: @L_Cleo Thanks, I've edited the question and figured out how the site works

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

Answer (score 0):

To display the details of a selected race, you don't necessarily need to do a new fetch. Instead, you can pass the selected race details directly from the RaceList component to the RaceDetails component using the navigation route params.

Comment: '<TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.section}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("RaceDetails", { 
          id: item.id,
          index: item.index,
          name: item.name,
          url: item.url, 
        })}
          >
        <RaceListCard iRace={item}></RaceListCard>
      </TouchableOpacity>' ERROR Argument of type '{ id: any; index: number; name: string; url: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ iRaceDetails: IRaceDetails; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type '{ iRaceDetails: IRaceDetails; }